# Bootstrap collpase, how to expand and close all the panel togheter

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button for collapse and expand all three panel togheter

`<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne-1,#collapseTwo-1,#collapseThree-1" ...></button>`

`<div id="#collapseOne-1" class="collapse in"></div>`
   `<div id="#collapseTwo-1" class="collapse in"></div>`
   `<div id="#collapseThree-1" class="collapse in"></div>`

The problem is that if one of the panel is already collapsed, it will expand,and viceversa.
However, I always want to expand or close all of them together when I click the button.

Do you have any idea of how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to collapse all of the panels at once:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
 $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Basically what the above code does is enable all the elements that have a collapse class to be collapsible and then it hides every one of them.
To show every panel you should use this code:

```
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
 $('.collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

You should also read this for more information: [Bootstrap Doc's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage)